# Formatting an array list into a specific format

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

The program I am writing will sort a hospital record that comes in a text file. The format of the text file is lastname,firstname,age,roomnumber, it will look exactly like this :

```
Franklin,Benjamin,74,18
Hamilton,Alexander,25,6
Thatcher,Margaret,65,3
Nixon,Richard,45,7
```

and has to be printed with a certain format, but the user will specify how they are sorted. The format will look like this when sorted by last name:

```
Last     First     Age      Room
Coolidge Calvin     24        27
Franklin Benjamin   74         8
Hamilton Alexander  50       123
Nixon    Richard    45         7
```

I have been stuck on trying to find a way to store the lines and still be able to print out the lines together in order to keep the information together. 
The Program has to be called through command-line and at the same time the program is called the user must specify the input file as the first argument (args[0]) and how to sort it as the second argument (args[1]). 
I have tried a few different ways but I keep getting stuck in the same place, what would be the best way to approach this?
This is the current code btw. and the comment blocks is old code I have tried and keep it around, just in case.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PatientRecord {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Servando Hernandez");
        System.out.println("Patient sorting Program.");

//
//        Scanner scan = null;
//        try
//      {
//            scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
//        } 
//      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
//      {
//           System.err.println("File path \"" + args[0] + "\" not found.");
//            System.exit(0);
//        }
//
//        ArrayList<String> lines=new ArrayList<String>();
//      
//        while(scan.hasNextLine())
//            lines.add(scan.nextLine());
//      
//      if(!(args.length == 0))
//      {
//          if(args[1] == lastname)
//          {
//              sortByLastName();
//          }
//          else if(args[1] == firstname)
//          {
//              sortByLastName();
//          }
//          else if(args[1] == age)
//          {
//              sortByAge();
//          }
//          else if(args[1] == roomnumber)
//          {
//              sortByRoomNumber();
//          }
//      }
//
        List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();
            while(scan.hasNextLine())
            {
                String[] values= scan.nextLine().split(",");
                patients.add(new Patient())
            }
            String sortType= args[1]

            switch(sortType))
            {
                case "firsname":

                break;
                case "lastname":
                break;
                case "age":
                break;
                case "roomnumber":
                break;
            }
    }
//  static String sortByLastName()
//  {
//       Collections.sort(lines);
//
//        for(String x : lines)
//            System.out.println(x);
//  }


class Patient
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
    int roomNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write a custom Comparator, let's call it PatientComparator. I will not implement the compare method completely, that's your job :-)

```
class PatientComparator implements Comparator<Patient> {
    String sortType;
    public PatientComparator(String sortType) {
        this.sortType = sortType;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Patient a, Patient b) {
        // TODO: write your switch case here
        return a.firstName.compareTo(b.firstName);
    }
```

Then, you can sort the Patients using your own Comparator:

```
Collections.sort(patients, new PatientComparator(arg[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I would start by dividing your exercise into two parts:

1- Calling the program through command-line with args[0]. Going through the file and showing the contents to the user (by respecting your format).

2- Add sorting to your script (this can be done in many ways; in general by overriding the compare method). Do step 1,sort with regarding to arg[1] and then the output.

To get you started I have done step 1 for you without doing any formatting on the output.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test3 {
    //You will store each line as an array of strings
    //then you store the lines in a list of arrays of strings
    public static ArrayList<String[]> mainList=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        try {
           //reading each line from the input file
            String line = br.readLine();
           //spliting the line by comma (,) which will return 
           //an array of strings - our names and numbers in string format
            while (line != null) {
                String[] lineElements=line.split(",");
                line = br.readLine();
                mainList.add(lineElements);
            }

        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        //showing to the user
        for (String[] line :mainList){
            for (String x:line){
                System.out.print(x+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

}
```

You simply compile with: `javac name.java`

Then you simply specify the file's location when you actually run it: `java name /path/to/your/file/`

I have run it using your sample file and I get this in the console (you simply have to format the output):

```
Franklin Benjamin 74 18 
Hamilton Alexander 25 6 
Thatcher Margaret 65 3 
Nixon Richard 45 7
```

There is much more to do but I think this is a great start!